# How to set the default font style in the TeXworks editor to bold

Tags: texworks

I want to be able to set the default font in the TeXworks editor to Courier Bold 12pt.

I currently have the typeface set to Courier and the fontsize set to 12pt by changing some settings in the menu `Edit`->`Preferences...`->`Editor`, however there doesn't seem to be any options available to setting the default font to bold. This renders the text too thin to be easily read on my monitor.

I already know that the font can be temporarily boldened at `Format`->`Fonts...` but this means I have to enter this menu each time I open a document.

Comment: on windows, texworks stores the default font in the registry.  unfortunately, the format is unclear: `MS Shell Dlg 2,14,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0`.  Surely someone on the mailing list would know.

Comment: here [link](https://tug.org/pipermail/texworks/2018q4/006823.html) we find:
`\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TUG\TeXworks

font family (for example "Courier New")
point size (default = 10)
pixel size (-1 = default)
style hint (what to do if requested family can't be found; 5 = AnyStyle =
default)
weight (50 = normal, 25 = light, 63 = semibold, 75 = bold, 87 = black)
italic (0 = no)
underline (0 = no)
strikeout (0 = no)
fixedPitch (1 = yes)
raw (0 = no)`

Comment: i made myself a .reg file with content `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\TeXworks]
"font"="Courier New,12,-1,5,75,0,0,0,0,0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this with some CSS. See [How can I set a dark theme in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383271/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texworks) for the general method of using a custom CSS file for TeXworks. In the `.css` file itself, you need this:

```
QTextEdit {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

(Short description of method: save `foo.css` somewhere, and run TeXworks with `texworks -stylesheet /path/to/foo.css`.)

Left, default weight, right bold weight.

[image: texworks]

Answer (score 0):

[image: texworkpref]

You can choose any font you like whether it is bold, light etc.,

Comment: Swisle knows about this, he's asking how you can set the weight of the chosen font to bold, as you can do under Format --> Font.

Comment: Since `Courier Bold` is different font (i.e. a different file) than `Courier`, it should appear in the list if it's installed on the OS, should not it?

Comment: Unfortunately ebo, `Courier Bold` does not appear in the drop down list.

Comment: @Swisle Then you probably don't have it installed. You could try googling for e.g. *courier bold download* and see if you find a font file that you can install to your system.